# How to silent print html content(Receipts)

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I am developing a POS system in PHP CodeIgniter, in which i need to print receipts from every transaction. I am able to generate dynamic receipts as per the products selected and able to print them also using iframes.

My issue is that I need to print those receipts silently(Without prompting anything on screen). I tried --kisok-printing also in chrome browser, While using Kiosk it opens the print dialog then automatically print the content with the default printer and the print dialog gets closed.

I even does not need the print dialoge to be shown and print without showing any effect on screen.

Please suggest me a way for the same.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't change a built in browser behaviour like that.

Answer (score 1):

I've sold the same issue using https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php for POS printer (it works great with EPSON TM-T20 only pure php:

```
<?php
/* Call this file 'hello-world.php' */
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
$connector = new FilePrintConnector("php://stdout");
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> close();
```

for none POS Printer (if it appear one day you need it) I suggest you try this blog https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/Print-HTML-from-PHP-to-client-printer-without-print-dialog-silently/ notice that I never try it before.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Write a wrapper UI in a native language to run on the kiosk that intercepts receipt print commands and performs them natively.
2. Attach the printer to the network and have your network server trigger the print to the network printer for you, e.g. using something like [PHP-Printer](https://github.com/jiminald/PHP-Printer).
3. Install a browser plug-in/extension for this purpose, e.g. [MeadCo ScriptX](http://scriptx.meadroid.com) (you'll need to handle the scenario where a client is missing the plugin, though).